# How to find a covered element in an image using Vuforia?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm trying to make an augmented reality application about chemistry using Vuforia and Unity3D. I will physically have a big image of periodic table of elements and some small spherical objects, and I don't know how to determine which element is covered by the sphere when I put it on the periodic table.  Does anyone have an idea or has done this already? I will next associate that chemical element with the sphere.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question is far to broad for this community. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).. in general: I'ld guess a periodic table is too symetric for Vuforia and not a good trackable ImageTarget ... otherwise I would say: recreate the periodic table in Unity, place it via Vuforia, use colliders and once the sphere enters an element's collider change it's type accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to try and track not only the position of the printed periodic table as Vuforia image target, but also the position of the 'small spherical objects' as Vuforia model targets. Whether or not that would work depends on the exact characteristics of those spherical objects and to which degree they are suitable for tracking as model targets. Otherwise consider replacing the spherical objects with alternative objects possibly with trackable stickers on them.